# while checking the ufw status for using nginx server in ubuntu app in windows, getting error. Can't get solved this issue?

Tags: server, firewall, nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ufw

```
 yabesh@LAPTOP-DLAQ7R33:~$ sudo ufw status
 ERROR: problem running iptables: iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table 
`filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
 Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I installed the Ubuntu app in windows 10 and I installed the Nginx server in the Ubuntu terminal and want to serve an HTML static                                  file in the Nginx server. Simply I want to serve a HTML static file from my windows pc to connect with Nginx server.  Can someone
please help, me to solve this issue??

Comment: I installed the Ubuntu app in windows 10 What does this mean Ubuntu is an OS not an app.

Comment: @David , sorry, actually I installed the ubuntu terminal app from Microsoft Store. I want to serve a HTML static file from my pc with Nginx server. While processing this I got this error and I don't get solution till now.

Comment: Do you mean WSL it is not an app. Ubuntu is in no way a terminal it is an OS It is still not clear what you are doing or trying to do.

Comment: @David, Yes, It is WSL. sorry, I am new to this. I am trying to deploy my HTML file to nginx server in WSL. I cannot activate Windows firewall. When putting "sudo ufw disable" it shows the same error "problem running iptables".

Comment: You still have not said what you are trying to do or expect to happen.

Comment: I have a folder that has HTML index file on my laptop. I want to host my file with my own domain with a reverse proxy Nginx free server. what am doing is correct?

Comment: @David, can you get my question. Is it the right way? need help to clarify this.

Comment: @Yabesh First off, Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I realize it's sometimes hard as a new user here to get the terminology "just right", so no worries.  I do recommend you read over [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) for some helpful tips.  First off, "Search and Research" -- Start with a search of *ufw wsl* to see if others here have asked similar questions (which they have).

Comment: But then, in the comments you clarify that you are trying to create a reverse proxy using Nginx to host a file on your domain.  *That* should be your real question, along with what you tried (`ufw`) and what didn't work.  Please *update* your question (or post a new question) with that info.  Thanks!

Comment: @David Thanks for coaxing the "real question" out of the OP :-).  Just a couple of clarifications, though -- On Windows with WSL, Ubuntu is installed as an "app" from the Microsoft Store.  Although you and I wouldn't consider it an "app", the terminology is fuzzy here since it comes packaged as an "Appx".  Also, even [Canonical has sometimes used](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/ubuntu-on-windows#1-overview) the (IMHO) *really poor* term "Ubuntu terminal."  Yes, I agree with you that it is certainly *not* a terminal, but I've learned to deal with new users calling it one due to Canonical's doc.